# NullReferenceException on managing close event of theconsole

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, callstack

this is my scenario: I have a console application and I'm trying to handle the "close event" of the console with this code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(new HandlerRoutine(ConsoleCtrlCheck), true);
.......
}

[DllImport("Kernel32")]
        public static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine Handler, bool Add);
        public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(CtrlTypes CtrlType);
        public enum CtrlTypes
        {
            CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
            CTRL_BREAK_EVENT,
            CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT,
            CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
            CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
        }
        private static bool ConsoleCtrlCheck(CtrlTypes ctrlType)
        {

            writeOnLogFile("Closed Manually");
            logWriter.WriteLine();
            logWriter.WriteLine();
            logWriter.Close();
            return true;
        }
```

Sometimes, when I close the console with the "X" button, this is the page that is shown to me: [No Source available](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dzbuwnfalrc2fs9/Immagine.png).
I try to look in the stack call, but there is nothing that is useful.
So, how i can resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem changing my code:

**Before**

```
public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(CtrlTypes CtrlType);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   SetConsoleCtrlHandler(new HandlerRoutine(ConsoleCtrlCheck), true);
  .......
}
```

**After**

```
public delegate bool HandlerRoutine(CtrlTypes CtrlType);
public static HandlerRoutine rout = new HandlerRoutine(ConsoleCtrlCheck);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   SetConsoleCtrlHandler(rout, true);
  .......
}
```

Initizialing an "HandlerRoutine" before it works perfectly.
Thank you anyway! I hope it can be useful to someone!

Answer (score 0):

Look, whether the handler is really attached every time.

This looks, as if the handler is not always properly attached.

Do You have a log entry, when this exception occurrs ?

Comment: I don't have a log entry, my code is in a try catch but there is no exception, it show me immediately that page.. Thank you for the answer..